# Temporarily disable android widget button

Tags: android, button, android-widget

I have a widget that consists of two buttons and an image. I would like to make it so the buttons get disabled for 30 seconds when the user presses one. How can this effect be achieved? This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="#55000000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/bulb"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="On"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg_clickable"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/offButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Off"
        android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg_clickable"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my current controller:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_ON = "Lights turning on";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_OFF = "Lights turning off";
    private String serverUrl = //put your server URL here

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_ON);
        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.onButton, actionPendingIntent);

        active = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_OFF);
        actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.offButton, actionPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_ON)) {
            Log.i("onReceive", ACTION_WIDGET_ON);
            new RestPostUtil().execute(serverUrl + "/lightsOn");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_OFF)) {
            Log.i("onReceive", ACTION_WIDGET_OFF);
            new RestPostUtil().execute(serverUrl + "/lightsOff");
        } else {
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `Timer`  and `runOnUiThread` to prevent `anr` just put the TimeImMS and you are good to go  (ex 1000 = 1s)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    button.setEnabled(false);

    Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
    buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }, TimeInMS);
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to `import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;`

and then use

```
try {
sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```